# Loop through objects of objects in js

Tags: javascript

I have a data like this:

```js
{
    "countries": {
        "US": {
            "details": {
                "code": 1,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "UK": {
            "details": {
                "code": 44,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to loop through it and extract `people` so I can loop through the people and display them on the site.

```js
var countries = {
    "countries": {
        "US": {
            "details": {
                "code": 1,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "UK": {
            "details": {
                "code": 44,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(countries.countries)) {
    //console.log(value);
        for (var people in value.people) {
                    console.log(people);
        }
}
```

But I keep getting 0, 1, how can I get the value of `people` array?

Comment: You should read about for..of and for..in I'll let the references here, [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array (and other data structures implementing the *iterable* interface) it's `for...of`, not `for...in` (which is for iterating over keys of an object).

```js
var countries = {
  "countries": {
    "US": {
      "details": {
        "code": 1,
        "population": ""
      },
      "people": [{
          "name": ""
        },
        {
          "name": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "UK": {
      "details": {
        "code": 44,
        "population": ""
      },
      "people": [{
          "name": ""
        },
        {
          "name": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(countries.countries)) {
  for (let people of value.people) {
    console.log(people);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj =  {
    "countries": {
        "US": {
            "details": {
                "code": 1,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "UK": {
            "details": {
                "code": 44,
                "population": ""
            },
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
for (let key in obj.countries) {
    console.log(obj.countries[key].people);
}
```